# Including functions from helper based on their type in Node

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have module *helper* which contains files such as *content*, *user* and similar for defining different helpers to be used in *router*. Here is the router:

**router.js**

```
var helper = require("./helper");

function index(response) {
    response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html; charset=utf-8"});
    response.write("<something>");
    response.end();
}
```

**helper/index.js**

```
var content = require("./content");
var user = require("./user");
var post = require("./post");
...
```

Now, I want to do something like this in router:

```
response.writeHead(200, Content.html());
```

To replace long hash. Is there an easy way to do this without classes (because I always need to initialize object if I want to use some functions from helper)? I know I can just do

```
exports.html = content.html;
```

And use *html()* instead but I'm interested if there's a way to do it like this?

Comment: I don't understand your question. What's wrong with simply exporting it?

Comment: @Gothdo Ya, it looks little complicated - because if I have the function with same name somewhere I need to change it's name. By this way, I can write both, Content.html() and Post.html(). You know, something like namespace in other languages.

Answer (score 0):

Identifiers starting with an uppercase letter (like `Content`) should be used only for classes.

Why not get rid of `helper/index.js` and directly import the modules you want?

```
const content = require('./helper/content')

function index(response) {
  response.writeHead(200, content.html());
  response.write("<something>");
  response.end();
}
```